# nth-of-type not working for a kind of div formation

Tags: html, css

```css
.woof_block_html_items select::nth-of-type(1){
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="woof_block_html_items">
    <select class="woof_select woof_select_product_cat woof_select_product_cat_0" name="product_cat"></select>
    <select class="woof_select woof_select_product_cat woof_select_product_cat_1" name="product_cat"></select>
    <select class="woof_select woof_select_product_cat woof_select_product_cat_2" name="product_cat"></select>
</div>
```

I am trying to hide the first child using css but its not working? Any idea?

Comment: `nth-of-type` is a selector and not a pseudo-element, so it requires a single `:`.

Comment: opps! you are right. my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one too many colons. You want:

```css
.woof_block_html_items select:nth-of-type(1) {
    display:none;
}
```

However, I fail to understand the use case for this. I recommend that you append a class (like 'deprecated' or whatever names your use case) and target `.woof_select.deprecated` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:first-of-type` for hide the first `<select>` element of its parent

```css
.woof_block_html_items select:first-of-type{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="woof_block_html_items">
    <select class="woof_select woof_select_product_cat woof_select_product_cat_0" name="product_cat"></select>
    <select class="woof_select woof_select_product_cat woof_select_product_cat_1" name="product_cat"></select>
    <select class="woof_select woof_select_product_cat woof_select_product_cat_2" name="product_cat"></select>
</div>
```

**OR** using `:first-child()`

```css
.woof_block_html_items select:first-child{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="woof_block_html_items">
    <select class="woof_select woof_select_product_cat woof_select_product_cat_0" name="product_cat"></select>
    <select class="woof_select woof_select_product_cat woof_select_product_cat_1" name="product_cat"></select>
    <select class="woof_select woof_select_product_cat woof_select_product_cat_2" name="product_cat"></select>
</div>
```

**OR** using `nth-child()`

```css
.woof_block_html_items select:nth-child(1){
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="woof_block_html_items">
    <select class="woof_select woof_select_product_cat woof_select_product_cat_0" name="product_cat"></select>
    <select class="woof_select woof_select_product_cat woof_select_product_cat_1" name="product_cat"></select>
    <select class="woof_select woof_select_product_cat woof_select_product_cat_2" name="product_cat"></select>
</div>
```